# Magento ver. 1.9.3.1 paypal standard redirecting to paypal express checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

We have updated our website from magento 1.6 to magento 1.9.3. Paypal standard was working fine in our previous magento version. In latest version there is Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout) instead of only Paypal standard. 
I have configured this payment method. Now issue is on my onestepcheckout page, i can see **paypal_express** instead of **paypal_standard** and when i an clicking on Place order button, its redirect me to express checkout page.

I hope some have idea how to fix this.

Comment: same here. Got exactly the same issue. Are you using IWD OPC?

Comment: Yes i am using IWD OPC.

Comment: What is your default currency and country in Magento?